# Can we render shadow on a transparent Plane in SceneKit

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I have used shader modifiers for Plane but its not working. Can anyone suggest me how to solve it?

```
let myShaderfragment = "#pragma transparent;\n" + "_output.color.a = 0.0;"
let myShaderSurface = "#pragma transparent;\n" + "_surface.diffuse.a = 0.0;"
 material.shaderModifiers = [SCNShaderModifierEntryPoint.fragment : myShaderfragment, SCNShaderModifierEntryPoint.surface : myShaderSurface]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SceneKit: Is it possible to cast an shadow on an Transparent Object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30975695/scenekit-is-it-possible-to-cast-an-shadow-on-an-transparent-object)

Comment: Yes Very Simple solution is here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46661670/drop-a-shadow-of-3d-object-on-the-plane-surface-using-arkit-scenekit/51450918#51450918

Answer (score 11):

The [SceneKit: What's New](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/604/) session from WWDC 2017 explains how to do that.

1. For the plane, use a material with [`constant`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnmaterial.lightingmodel/1462538-constant) as its [`lightingModel`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnmaterial/1462518-lightingmodel). It's the cheapest one.
2. This material will have [`writesToDepthBuffer`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnmaterial/1462545-writestodepthbuffer) set to `true` and [`colorBufferWriteMask`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnmaterial/2867554-colorbufferwritemask) set to `[]` (empty option set). That way the plane will write in the depth buffer, but won't draw anything on screen.
3. Set the light's [`shadowMode`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnshadowmode) to [`deferred`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnshadowmode/1523758-deferred) so that shadows are not applied when rendering the objects themselves, but as a final post-process.

Comment: I have a similar problem, but I need to draw shadows on transparent floor, but also set SceneView.backgroundColor to clear. For some reason if I do this, then shadow is not visible. More info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52654624/scenekit-shadow-on-a-transparent-scnfloor I would appreciate if anyone could help resolve this

Answer (score 1):

There's a dedicated lighting model now (SCNLightingModelShadowOnly) to only render shadows

Comment: I'm unable to get this to show any shadows on iOS 13.x, though it seems to work in the SceneKit editor in Xcode. Do you have some sample code that works on iOS?