# ARKit –Drop a shadow of 3D object on the plane surface

Tags: swift, xcode, scenekit, augmented-reality, arkit

This is the function that I use to display object on the plane surface.

```
private func loadScene(path: String) -> SCNNode {

    let spotLight = SCNLight()
    spotLight.type = SCNLight.LightType.probe

    spotLight.spotInnerAngle = 30.0
    spotLight.spotOuterAngle = 80.0
    spotLight.castsShadow = true

    let result = SCNNode()
    result.light = spotLight
    result.position = SCNVector3(-10.0, 20.0, 10.5)
    result.addChildNode(result)

    let scene = SCNScene(named: path)!
    for node in scene.rootNode.childNodes {
        result.addChildNode(node)
    }       
    return result
}
```

I want to display shadow on the plane surface like this image.

[image: Image with Shadow on the plane surface]

When I set spotlight type like below

```
spotLight.type = SCNLight.LightType.directional
```

It shows the object itself with light/dark shadow and does not drop the shadow on the surface.

Can someone please guide me how can I achieve the output as shown in the image?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can we render shadow on a transparent Plane in SceneKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45505471/can-we-render-shadow-on-a-transparent-plane-in-scenekit)

Answer (score 5):

// To Add Shadow on 3D Model Just Copy Paste this code and it will appear a shadow of 3D Model on Ground

```
let flourPlane = SCNFloor()
let groundPlane = SCNNode()
let groundMaterial = SCNMaterial()
groundMaterial.lightingModel = .constant
groundMaterial.writesToDepthBuffer = true
groundMaterial.colorBufferWriteMask = []
groundMaterial.isDoubleSided = true
flourPlane.materials = [groundMaterial]
groundPlane.geometry = flourPlane
//
mainNode.addChildNode(groundPlane)
// Create a ambient light
let ambientLight = SCNNode()
ambientLight.light = SCNLight()
ambientLight.light?.shadowMode = .deferred
ambientLight.light?.color = UIColor.white
ambientLight.light?.type = SCNLight.LightType.ambient
ambientLight.position = SCNVector3(x: 0,y: 5,z: 0)
// Create a directional light node with shadow
let myNode = SCNNode()
myNode.light = SCNLight()
myNode.light?.type = SCNLight.LightType.directional
myNode.light?.color = UIColor.white
myNode.light?.castsShadow = true
myNode.light?.automaticallyAdjustsShadowProjection = true
myNode.light?.shadowSampleCount = 64
myNode.light?.shadowRadius = 16
myNode.light?.shadowMode = .deferred
myNode.light?.shadowMapSize = CGSize(width: 2048, height: 2048)
myNode.light?.shadowColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.75)
myNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0,y: 5,z: 0)
myNode.eulerAngles = SCNVector3(-Float.pi / 2, 0, 0)
// Add the lights to the container
mainNode.addChildNode(ambientLight)
mainNode.addChildNode(myNode)
// End
```

Comment: I am used your code it's work but i am facing one issue.
Some time shadow is not display at first time. If i am scale down or rotate object then shadow is appear. 

Do you have any idea why this happen ?

Comment: On iOS 13, you need to change `groundMaterial.colorBufferWriteMask = []` into `groundMaterial.colorBufferWriteMask = SCNColorMask.alpha` for it to work

Comment: @QuangTran I change to `.alpha` but instead of shadow I have a big black plane!. How can i fix this?

Comment: @Mc.Lover try to recheck shadow color of direction light. Make sure it have an alpha value.

Comment: @QuangTran I changed it to `groundMaterial.colorBufferWriteMask = .all` and worked

Answer (score 2):

This edited version of the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51450918/4156490) worked for me. I used material with shadowOnly model.

[image]

```
let flourPlane = SCNFloor()
let groundPlane = SCNNode()
let groundMaterial = SCNMaterial()
groundMaterial.lightingModel = .shadowOnly
flourPlane.materials = [groundMaterial]
groundPlane.geometry = flourPlane
//
node.addChildNode(groundPlane)
// Create a ambient light
let ambientLight = SCNNode()
ambientLight.light = SCNLight()
ambientLight.light?.shadowMode = .deferred
ambientLight.light?.color = UIColor.white
ambientLight.light?.type = SCNLight.LightType.ambient
ambientLight.position = SCNVector3(x: 0,y: 5,z: 0)
// Create a directional light node with shadow
let myNode = SCNNode()
myNode.light = SCNLight()
myNode.light?.type = SCNLight.LightType.directional
myNode.light?.color = UIColor.white
myNode.light?.castsShadow = true
myNode.light?.automaticallyAdjustsShadowProjection = true
myNode.light?.shadowSampleCount = 64
myNode.light?.shadowRadius = 16
myNode.light?.shadowMode = .deferred
myNode.light?.shadowMapSize = CGSize(width: 2048, height: 2048)
myNode.light?.shadowColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.75)
myNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0,y: 1,z: -3)
myNode.eulerAngles = SCNVector3(-Float.pi / 2, 0, 0)
// Add the lights to the container
node.addChildNode(ambientLight)
node.addChildNode(myNode)
```